# I wanted to insert data into Microsoft sql table but encountered incorrect syntax near ' '

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have been trying to insert data into Microsoft SQL table but it says incorrect syntax near ''. What could have gone wrong?

This is my data:

```
insert into Course_Relation
('DBA','Diploma_in_Business_Administration', 'SB' ,500.00),
('DBIT','Diploma_in_Business_and_Information_Technology','DMIT',700.00,100.00),
('DDM','Diploma_in_Digital_Media','DMIT',1000.00,900.00),
('DFI','Diploma_in_Business_Administration','SB',800.00),
('DISM','Diploma_in_Infocomm_Security_Management','DMIT',900.00,300.00),
('DIT','Diploma_in_Information_Technology','DMIT',650.00,450.00),
select * from Course_Relation
```

Comment: What is structure of table `Course_Relation`? In 2nd row of your code it have **4** values, but in 3rd row, it have **5** values? And near last row before `select` it should be `;` not `,`

Comment: And you really should always include the list of columns in an insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect, and you must provide the same number of columns for each row in a table constructor.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

```
INSERT INTO Course_Relation
VALUES ('DBA','Diploma_in_Business_Administration', 'SB' ,500.00, NULL),
('DBIT','Diploma_in_Business_and_Information_Technology','DMIT',700.00,100.00),
('DDM','Diploma_in_Digital_Media','DMIT',1000.00,900.00),
('DFI','Diploma_in_Business_Administration','SB',800.00, NULL),
('DISM','Diploma_in_Infocomm_Security_Management','DMIT',900.00,300.00),
('DIT','Diploma_in_Information_Technology','DMIT',650.00,450.00);

SELECT * FROM Course_Relation;
```